# How to make google transliteration happens on keyup event instead of space bar click

Tags: javascript

After page loads for the first time, if I select any other language in dropdown, it is giving malayalam language instead of elected language, but after selecting the same or another language for the second time, it is translating correctly. Can anyone please help me to solve this.

My code:

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        google.load("elements", "1", {
          packages: "transliteration"
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                sourceLanguage: 'en',
                //After page loaded, ml is defaulted
                destinationLanguage: ['ml', 'hi', 'kn', 'ta', 'te'],
                shortcutKey: 'ctrl+m',
                transliterationEnabled: true
            }       
            var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
            control.showControl('translControl');
            $("input").keypress(function(){ 
                var ids = ["language"];
                control.makeTransliteratable(ids);
            });
        });

    </script>

    <body>
        <form>
            <div id ="translControl"></div>
            <input type="textbox name="ta"  rows="6"  id="language" cols="6" style="width:600px;height:218px" ></input>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `control.makeTransliteratable(ids);` inside a keypress event? I have never used this, but the [first example i found on google](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started) calls `control.makeTransliteratable()` inside the onload function, not within a keypress

Comment: I tried to activate translietation for every keypress instead of space bar click, but it didn't work with this code